# Mover elemento para cima de elemento onde cursor está

Tags: jquery, animação

Eu tenho este codigo: queria que o '#hoverLayer' se movesse (animate) para um dos '#bts' ('#bt1','#bt2','#bt3','#bt4'), dependendo onde o cursor está. Alguma ideia?

html:

```
<div id="bts">
    <div id="hoverLayer"></div>
    <div id="bt1"></div>
    <div id="bt2"></div>
    <div id="bt3"></div>
    <div id="bt4"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#hoverLayer {
    display: block;
    width: 155px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    position: absolute;
}
#bts {
    display: block;
    width: 620px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
#bt1, #bt2, #bt3, #bt4 {
    width: 155px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Js: isto foi o que fiz até agora, agarrar o id do elemento que está hover... só falta agarrar a sua localização (não faço ideia como) e dar ao '#hoverLayer' a mesma.

```
$('#bts div[id^="bt"]').mouseenter(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Comment: Cria um JSFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mesh18av/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes atingir o teu objetivo da seguinte forma:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/7mo5e6q5/)

```
$('#bts > div:not("#hoverLayer")').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $target = $(this);
    $('#hoverLayer').css({"left":$target.position().left});
});
```

### Explicação

Quando o cursor esta no elemento `#bts` por cima de um elemento filho que não é o `#hoverLayer`, atribuimos a definição de CSS `left` do elemento onde o rato está ao elemento que queremos mover.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz um arranjo (http://jsfiddle.net/mesh18av/3/) mas era isso (position()) que faltava... Obgado

Answer (score 0):

[Exemplo com offset()](http://jsfiddle.net/mesh18av/2/)

```
    $('#bts div[id^="bt"]').mouseenter(function() {
      var offset = $( this ).offset();
      $("#hoverLayer").offset({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left });
    })
```